# Get full date when DateTime.DayOfYear and Year is given

Tags: c#, date

Is there a possibility to get the full date out of the year and the dayOfYear value?
For example: today is Thursday, 19th of february 2015.
The dayOfYear-Value of today is 50.

If I have the value 75 and the year 2010, how am I able to get the matching date?
It could be displayed in a textBox, dateTimePicker, whatever.
But you only have the information year & dayOfYear.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
DateTime day = New DateTime(2010, 1, 1).AddDays(75 - 1);
```

First get the first day of the year, then add necessary day count minus one (you are already on the first date of the year) days to the first day and you are there.